# Error while trying to install Coqui AI TTS to Python

Tags: python-3.x, coqui

I am getting this error when trying to install Coqui TTS for my Python Project. C++ Build tools version 14 is already properly installed. Please advise on how to fix this. Thank you!

Error Text:

```
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
 
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tts
Failed to build tts
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tts, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
 
C:\Users\chris>      copying TTS\bin\compute_attention_masks.py -> temp_build\TTS\bin
```

I tried to look up the error and went into the Coqui community chatroom and asked in the Learn Python Discord but got no answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens on windows os devices mostly. there are 3 ways

- install **git cli in your windows device** and run commands from there ( alike linux)
- use **linux os**
- the easiest way should use **vm or colab/ azure/ kaggle karnel** types platform for running your model

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for a simple Python installation to use CoquiTTS:
I would recommend using `conda` as your environment manager, but `pip` as your package manager (best of both worlds in my opinion). Using Linux is a plus! (if not use WSL in Windows, that's your best bet)

If you don't have conda installed use this [link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/) to install the latest Miniconda (simple and lightweight but has all the benefits of Anaconda)
For example, you could do the following,

```bash
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
sha256sum Miniconda3-py39_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
# should be: 78f39f9bae971ec1ae7969f0516017f2413f17796670f7040725dd83fcff5689
bash Miniconda3-py39_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Once that is done, you create a new conda environment and install [TTS](https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS)

```bash
conda create --name coqui
conda activate coqui
conda install conda python=3.9 # works like a charm

# for a simple installation, just do
pip install TTS

# for a developer installation, do
git clone https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS
cd TTS
pip install -e .[all,dev,notebooks]
```